# Connect two webparts by author/person

Tags: 2013, connected-web-parts

Im trying to create filter connection of two webparts in display view form of list by using "Author" Columns, but not working yet.

It is possible to create connection by this way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Follow these support articles (for 2010, but process is the same for 2013):

- [Connect data in Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-54a36fda-019c-49b3-ad33-0cd94bf70c1e)
- [Connect a Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-1aabfd67-2e2e-4912-9230-6cb43a2c140a)

To filter by current user, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ret9lkuCtjY).

Please comment on my post if you are having specific problem or exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but im trying to create this conection at my Sharepoint Foundtaion Site, where is no User Filter Web part :(

Comment: Please add some details. SPF 2013, and you want to have two webparts connected by `Author` field. What are those webparts? List View + another List View?

Comment: I have solved my problem by Workflow that set (Person/Author) ID to new column and then I set webpart filters by theese columns :)